# Why product-info's height does not scale to card-component?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm currently stuck [at this, its a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji5Qx.png):

I need both product-info and image heights to be the same, but for some reason using height: 100% in CSS desktop version doesn't works. Maybe giving card-component and especific height would work?. Also any suggestions to my code are welcomed, specifly with responsive design's stuff.

I'm new with CSS and I'm doing this for practice.

This is my HTML and CSS code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 530px)">
  <title>Product preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="card-component">

      <figure class="image-container">
        <picture>
          <source media="(min-width: 530px)" srcset="./images/image-product-desktop.jpg">
          <img src="./images/image-product-mobile.jpg" class="card-component__image" alt="product image">
        </picture>
      </figure>
      
      <div class="card-component__product-info">
        
        <span>PERFUME</span>

        <div class="card-component__product-description">
          <h1>Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
          <p>
            A floral, solar and voluptuos
            interpretation composed by Oliver
            Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House
            of CHANEL.
          </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-component__price">
          <h1>$149.99</h1>
          <p>$169.99</p>
        </div>

        <button class="card-button">
          <img src="./images/icon-cart.svg" alt="cart icon">
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS: Mobile**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --dark-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
    --cream: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
    --very-dark-blue: hsl(212, 21%, 14%);
    --dark-grayish-blue: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
    --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

main {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--cream);
}

.card-component {
    width: 92.5%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 700px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-component .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.card-component .card-component__image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
}

.card-component__product-info {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    color: var(--dark-grayish-blue);

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
    background-color: var(--white);
    
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
}

.card-component__product-info span {
    display: block;

    letter-spacing: 0.5rem;

    font-size: 1.2rem;

    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card-component__product-description {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card-component__product-description h1 {
    font-family: "Fraunces";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.4rem;

    line-height: 3.5rem;

    color:black; 

    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.card-component__product-description p {
    line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.card-component__price {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.card-component__price h1 {
    font-family: "Fraunces";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.4rem;

    color: var(--dark-cyan);
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.card-component__price p {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.card-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;

    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--white);

    border: none;
    background-color: var(--dark-cyan);
    border-radius: 0.8rem;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-button img {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.card-button:hover {
    background-color: var(--very-dark-blue);
}
```

**CSS:Desktop**

```
.card-component {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.card-component .card-component__image {
    border-radius: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
}

.card-component__product-info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) style.

Comment: you want to set same size for image and card view right? may i know your desktop image size?

Comment: @Elango 600x900

Comment: @Ethan kind o help, established it to 1 / 1.4, thanks